# Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED any suggestions

Tags: android, manifest, malformed

** everyone with the same question has specific problems none of the have worked for me i've had more problems making this project than any other i've had.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.BinaryRelics"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
```

**im pretty sure that the problem is somewhere between here and my last intent filter line**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Homescreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.BinaryRelics.Arcademode"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_arcademode"
        android:parentActivityName="com.BinaryRelics.Homescreen" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.BinaryRelics.Homescreen" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data>
        </meta-data>
    </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: you have an empty meta-data in your activity, not sure you are supposed to have that.

Comment: about 9 questions in the `related` column could contain the answer to your question.

Comment: also, this manifest is so short, trial and error to determine which piece is causing the error would be my route, not giving up and asking the internet.

Comment: anything from the console,logcat,or problems tab?

Comment: Seconding @nobalG's question. For this error, you will typically see info in Logcat explaining exactly what went wrong.